# batch file copy from subdirectories and rename

Tags: windows, batch-file

Problem: I am trying to copy *.pdf from multiple subdirectories. These *.pdf can have the same name and i need to rename them. I also needed to copy the *.pdf by date from January to present but i was just trying to get the copy to work first.

My Attempt:

```
pushd "S:\Clients\"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir S:\Clients\*.pdf /s /b') do (
if exist "C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Jan-March\%%f" ( xcopy "S:\Clients\%%f" "C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Jan-March\%%f" 'dir /s /d )
)
popd
pause
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: I think you lost me, so you're trying to pull a bunch of `.pdf` files from a folder on the home of a drive called `S:\` to a folder on your desktop? Are the sub-folders in the `jan-march` folder? If so duplicate names are expected, but then what format do you wish them in? ( _rand_file.ext_ becomes _rand_file-2.ext_ ? )